# connecting MQTT to cumulocity tenant

Tags: mqtt, cumulocity

I am trying to connect to our cumulocity tenant using MQTT lens but it is showing the status as disconnected. I am a bit doubtful regarding the tenant name. Is it the same as the beginning of the URI?
for example the link to my tenant is:
https://atlascopco.cumulocity.com
so the username should be atlascopco/username?

[image: settings for MQTT Lens]

Comment: From your screenshot everything looks fine. Do you get any information why connection is not established (like permission denied or something like this). Unfortunatly MQTTLens is a bit shy in this regard

Comment: No i dont get any error or exceptions i just see on the status "disconected"

Comment: hostname and port are working so only the credentials are left. If you are sure you entered everything correctly you can also try MQTTFx as client tool. It will give you the error happening on the connect

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

The tenant name is the part before ".cumulocity.com". So your guess is right.

best regards
Michael

Comment: I am not able to connect to the tenant then the mqtt lens shows the status as disconnected. The rest of the details are correct can you please assist me with what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have here an example about MQTT BOX. But at first glance your access data / config data looks right.

- MQTT Client Name: Cumulocity MQTT Device
- Protocol: mqtt/tcp
- Username: TENANT/USERNAME
- Host: TENANT.cumulocity.com:1883
- Will-Topic: Will - Topic
- Will - QoS: 0 - Almost Once

With this configuration I can connect my MQTT Test Device via MQTT BOX and send data.